# Unity - Outline doesn't show on UI Text

Tags: user-interface, text, unity-game-engine, outline

I'm trying to give an outline to a UI Text element, but it doesn't show at all. Why is it not working? Here is a screenshot of my project:

[image]

Comment: Event though Galandil's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42685374/3785314) should fix your problem, you should be using [TextMesh Pro](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84126) which is now free and will also integrated into future Unity version.

Comment: @Programmer Wow, I didn't know about this package, thanks for letting me know that, it's a great tool indeed.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the screenshot, the color of the outline has the alpha set to 0, so it's completely transparent.

Change it to a non-0 value and you'll see the outline.

Comment: I noticed that too. This is very likely the problem.

Comment: I didn't even notice that when setting the color. In fact, after reading your answer, it took me a minute to see where the hell I could change the alpha. Indeed that was the problem, I have an outline now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `Mercador` object lower than `Jugar` in Canvas hierarchy. The highest Canvas child is behind all, lowest - in front of.